# How can i prevent duplicates from being created

Tags: excel, excel-2007, spreadsheet, vba

I've created an excel spreadsheet which will be tracking faulty assets that have been sent back from our external agents, I have two tabs that will be the main focus of this spreadsheet. Tab 1 will be the tested assets tab and Tab 2 will be awaiting testing. So once any asset that gets sent back will be manually logged on the awaiting testing tab, but once it's been tested I've created a vba code that will export anything that's been marked with a "Y" meaning it's been tested on to the Tested assets tab.

But the problem i have here is that one asset can come in to testing and be sent back out to the field to our engineers more than once, so if it comes back to be tested again and gets logged on the awaiting testing and once it's been tested and exported to the tested assets tab it duplicates what already is on the tested asset tab and i get two cells with the same data. Is there anyway i can put in another line of code that will prompt me on a duplicate before it exports it. See code below;

```
Sub automove()

Dim SerialNo As String
Dim AwaitTestLastRow, PasteToRow As Long

Sheets("Awaiting Testing").Select

AwaitTestLastRow = Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row

For x = AwaitTestLastRow To 3 Step -1

    If Range("c" & x).Value = "Y" Or Range("c" & x).Value = "y" Then

        SerialNo = Range("a" & x).Value
        Rows(x).Delete

        Sheets("Tested Assets").Select

        Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SerialNo
        Range("e1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = SerialNo

        PasteToRow = Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row

        Range("b3:d3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("b" & PasteToRow & ":d" & PasteToRow).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Range("f3").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("f" & PasteToRow & ":f" & PasteToRow).Select

        ActiveSheet.Paste

        Sheets("Awaiting Testing").Select

    End If

Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways of checking for duplicates. In the code below, I've used a `.Find` function on the "Tested Assets" worksheet. If the return object is `Nothing` then it's a new item, if it's a `Range` then we know the address of your duplicate. It's not necessarily the quickest way (a `Collection` might be quicker, for example), but the `.Find` function is still pretty snappy and as, you'll see in my next comment, I wanted to have the range address.

I've put some code below that instead of prompting you for a duplicate, records the frequency with which the same item is returning to the test lab - might be of some use to you for tracking a repeat offender. However, if you don't want that then delete the 4 lines and replace with `MsgBox asset(1, 1) & " is a duplicate."`

I've adjusted your code slightly to speed it up, and watch out for declaring two variables on the same line as each variable must have its own declaration type. In your line: `Dim AwaitTestLastRow, PasteToRow As Long`, the `AwaitTestLastRow` variable isn't a `Long` (it's actually not typed ie a `Variant`).

```
Sub AutoMove_v2()
    Dim awaitingRange As Range
    Dim testedRange As Range
    Dim flaggedRange As Range
    Dim newRow As Range
    Dim dupCell As Range
    Dim testFlag As String
    Dim asset As Variant
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim frq As Long

    'Initialise the parameters
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Awaiting Testing")
        Set awaitingRange = .Range("A3", _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tested Assets")
        Set testedRange = .Range("A1", _
                            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With

    'Loop through the awaiting sheet to find assets for transferral
    For Each cell In awaitingRange
        testFlag = UCase(cell.Offset(, 2).value)
        If testFlag = "Y" Then
            If flaggedRange Is Nothing Then
                Set flaggedRange = cell
            Else
                Set flaggedRange = Union(flaggedRange, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Identify duplicates or transfer new assets
    For Each cell In flaggedRange
        asset = cell.Resize(, 4).value
        Set dupCell = testedRange.Cells.Find(What:=asset(1, 1), _
                                             After:=testedRange.Cells(1), _
                                             LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                             LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                             MatchCase:=True)

        If dupCell Is Nothing Then
            'It's a new entry so transfer the values
            Set newRow = testedRange.Cells(testedRange.Cells.Count).Offset(1)
            Set testedRange = Union(testedRange, newRow)
            newRow.Resize(, 4) = asset
        Else
            'It's a duplicate so increment the frequency counter
            frq = dupCell.Offset(, 5).value
            If frq = 0 Then frq = 1
            frq = frq + 1
            dupCell.Offset(, 5) = frq
        End If
    Next

    'Delete the transferred rows
    flaggedRange.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it's helped me a lot. The frequency part is great but i can't seem to figure out where on my spreadsheet it's recording the frequency, so I've switched it back to the prompt. Thanks once again.